# bootstrap multiselect checkboxes should be visible on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I want the [bootstrap multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) to be visible on the page by default and it shouldn't toggle. Its functionality should be similar to default multiselect with check boxes.

I added this style to make it look as if it is on the page:

```
ul.multiselect-container{
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

But I also want that it shouldn't get hidden when I click outside the page.
Any Idea?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @Sachin, reply to my answer whether it is correct or not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the below code to show `checkboxes` `onLoad`

```
if ($('select').next().hasClass('btn-group')) {
    $('select').next().addClass('open');
}
```

Then I used `onDropdownHidden` to prevent dropdown close

```
$('.multiselect').multiselect({
    onDropdownHidden: function (event) {
        $('select').next().addClass('open');
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x1d541nx/2/)